# How would I mathematically calculate the odds of throwing a 7 from 2 dice?

Tags: probability, statistics, combinations

I can find the answer by getting all the combinations that add up to $7$ with $(d_1, d_2)$, such as $(1,6),(2,5),(3,4),(4,3),(5,2),(6,1).$ But what formula could I use instead?

Comment: Why do you think there should be a formula other than the ratio of "favorable outcomes" vs. "all possible outcomes"? Ok, with just two dice there is a formula, but with three or more it becomes progressively more messy.

Comment: There are formulas that generalize or explain what you did, but I don't really think there are formulas that provide a simpler alternative calculation.  I may be wrong (because one can never really know EVERY way to do a problem), but I don't think you can avoid asking and then enumerating what ways you can roll a 7.

Answer (score 1):

Technically it is: $\sum_{d_1=1}^6\sum_{d_2=1}^6 \tfrac {\mathbf 1_{d_1+d_2=7}}{36} = \dfrac 16$

But really, all that is saying is only count outcomes where indicated.

There are not any more sophisticated ways to calculate the probability than this, and why would you seek them?

For each of the results the first die, one result in six of the other die will yield the required sum.   Done.

Answer (score 1):

In our case their is a quick way to go about,

---

Let $x$ be the number of the first die, $y$ be the number of the second die. We are interested in the number of ways,

$$x+y=7$$

Or,

$$(x-1)+(y-1)=5$$

$$u+v=5$$

Where $u,v \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$. This is a well known problem, solved by stars and bars.

The answer to the problem the number of the number of non negative solutions to $x_1+x_2+...+x_n=k$ is,

$${n+k-1 \choose k}$$

---

In our case we see our probability is $\frac{{2+5-1 \choose 5}}{6^2}$. Notice in our case restricting $u,v \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ doesn't matter because $u+v=5$ so $u$ and $v$ must already  be in such set.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you use the word "odds" to mean probability. The probability of throwing two dice such that the numbers add up to 7 are the sum of $\frac{1}{36}$ for all combinations 
$(1,6),(2,5),(3,4),(4,3),(5,2),(6,1)$.

$$\frac{1}{36} 6= \frac{1}{6}$$